Why can't I use .deleteSelf for CKRecord.setParent(...)?
I'd like to:

Use hierarchical sharing with CloudKit, with a shared root record, and a tree of children that automatically get shared alongside.
Have the entire hierarchy be deleted automatically when deleting the root record.

So, presumably, I want to use childRecord.setParent(rootRecord) to set up this hierarchy. But the docs say:

The resulting CKReference has an action of CKRecord.ReferenceAction.none.

(As opposed to ReferenceAction.deleteSelf)
Why? I'd like to make it so that when the owner of the root record deletes a root record, it automatically deletes the entire hierarchy underneath it.
As an alternative, I tried manually setting up the parent child relationship using:
let parentReference = CKRecord.Reference(recordID:parentRecordId, action: .deleteSelf)
record.setValue(parentReference, forKey: "parent")

But then breaks the sharing hierarchy - the children don't get shared, presumably because although they reference the parent, they don't have an "official" parent-child relationship according to CloudKit.
Is it not possible to have both hierarchical sharing and cascade deletion in CloudKit?
Edit: Furthermore, when using setParent, it seems impossible to delete the parent unless all children are deleted first, presumably because they would be orphaned. CloudKit Console gives a non-descriptive error, and when deleting via CKSyncEngine it gives the error "Record delete would violate validating reference, rejecting update".
